# Sequence Diagram return a new constructed Object

Tags: oop, uml, sequence-diagram

I am drawing a Sequence Diagram where the scenario is.
1. an Actor calls :Table::query(query:String)

2. :Table::query Calls :Connection::execute(query)
3. :Connection::execute <> a new :Row Object
4. :Connection::execute calls :Row::fillData(result)
5. :Connection::execute returns :Row
6. ...... There are More

But I am Stuck in Step 5

I cant Understand how to draw that, :Connection::execute returning the newly Constructed Row itself, in a Standard way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, maybe simple return message from :Connection to :Table with that result will suffice:
[sequence diagram with workflow described in the question, result is carried by the return/reply message http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e33283f7af.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e33283f7af.png)

Comment: please fix your image. It's much too long.

Comment: But there is no Obvious specification that says that the :Row Object is returned. and one more question. as :Connection is CREATING a :Row Shouldn't :Row bit lower than :Table and :Connection ??

Comment: @user256007 I am not sure about what do you mean by :Row::fillData(result) I do not know what the result is, maybe if you were more specific... And I guess you are right about the lifelines. Maybe tommorrow I will correct it... Try to be more specific about how fillData works